# Can't remove text decoration from <a> element

Tags: html, css

I can't move the text decoration from the "download text".

Incidentally - I'd also like to be able to center it against the image but can't work out how to do that either... Code below :)

```css
img {
  vertical-align: text-middle;
  float: left;
}

p {
  font-size: 220%;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a download="GLV-11.pdf" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?
     export=download&id=1IzZeCDoRRMRudo3egijFimr6eJaHgMAm">
  <p class="brochure"> Brochure Download <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?
    export=download&id=1Rh5twX_t1vEQf198L4le5qCzg8KGxfbc" alt="Brochure Download" align="center"> </p>
</a>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "center against"? Is this vertically center alongside the image?

Answer (score 3):

You need to target the `a` element itself:

```
a {
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `text-decoration` property on the containing `a` (anchor) tag, e.g:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
img {
  vertical-align: text-middle;
  float: left;
}

p {
  font-size: 220%;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  line-height: 73px; /* equal to height of img element */
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a download="GLV-11.pdf" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?
 export=download&id=1IzZeCDoRRMRudo3egijFimr6eJaHgMAm">

  <p class="brochure"> Brochure Download <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?
export=download&id=1Rh5twX_t1vEQf198L4le5qCzg8KGxfbc" alt="Brochure Download" align="center"> </p>

</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text-decoration needs to be defined for the `a` tag itself. It's also common to apply different settings to the different states (link/hover etc.) as shown below.

Concerning the vertically centered alignment, you can use `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` as shown below. (Note: I moved the text to be after the image in the code)

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 220%;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

a:link, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a download="GLV-11.pdf" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?
     export=download&id=1IzZeCDoRRMRudo3egijFimr6eJaHgMAm">
  <p class="brochure"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?
    export=download&id=1Rh5twX_t1vEQf198L4le5qCzg8KGxfbc" alt="Brochure Download">  Brochure Download </p>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

For anchor tags, we remove the text-decoration css property.

learn more about this property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

Also to center ,a tag with image, you can assign 'a' tag with a classname, say 'brochure-download--container'
You can modify your html like this:

```
<a class="brochure-download--container" download="GLV-11.pdf" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1IzZeCDoRRMRudo3egijFimr6eJaHgMAm"><p class="brochure"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Rh5twX_t1vEQf198L4le5qCzg8KGxfbc" alt="Brochure Download" align="center"><span>Brochure Download</span></p>
</a>
```

You can then add this CSS for aligning to center and remove text-decoration from anchor tag.

```
a.brochure-download--container p{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;/*bring content to center*/
}
```

Btw, flex property still is not supported in all browsers and might require vendor prefixes..you can check it [here](https://caniuse.com/)

I will leave you with discovering vendor prefixes(google is really helpful when one starts learning new stuff)